SwiftUI gesture blocks UITouch
I have two views in my app - one that uses a SwiftUI view with a gesture (drag gesture), and another that uses UIKit multi touch.
When the multi touch starts, I can continue to use the drag gesture on the SwiftUI view and they work in unison.
However, when I start the drag gesture on the SwiftUI, the UIKit view does not receive any new touches (existing touches with touchesMoved still works).
I've found a couple of other posts referring to this issue, but there has been no resolution and those threads are older now.
Is this a "bug" or a "feature"? :-)
Since I still receive touchesMoved on existing touches and don't receive new touches when the drag gesture is being used, it seems to point in the direction of "bug"?
Any pointers or tips or solutions greatly appreciated!
I've created a reproducible test case:
import SwiftUI

public typealias TouchCallback = ([CGPoint]) -> Void

import UIKit

class MultitouchViewIOS: UIView {
    
    var callback: TouchCallback = { _ in }
    var touches = Set<UITouch>()
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.touches.formUnion(touches)
        callback(self.touches.map { $0.location(in: nil)})
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        callback(self.touches.map { $0.location(in: nil)})
    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.touches.subtract(touches)
        callback(self.touches.map { $0.location(in: nil)})
    }

    override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.touches.subtract(touches)
        callback(self.touches.map { $0.location(in: nil)})
    }
}

struct MultitouchView: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    var callback: TouchCallback = { _ in }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MultitouchViewIOS {
        let view = MultitouchViewIOS()
        view.callback = callback
        view.isMultipleTouchEnabled = true
        return view
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: MultitouchViewIOS, context: Context) {
        uiView.callback = callback
    }
}

And here is the SwiftUI view with drag gestures
import SwiftUI

struct TestView2: View {

    @GestureState var translation: CGSize = .zero
    @GestureState private var fingerLocation: CGPoint? = nil
    
    @State var stop: Bool = true

    
    var fingerDrag: some Gesture {
        DragGesture()
            .updating($fingerLocation) { (value, fingerLocation, transaction) in
                print("\(value.location)")
                fingerLocation = value.location
            }
    }
    
    func simpleDrag(for metrics: GeometryProxy) -> some Gesture {
        DragGesture().updating($translation) { value, state, _ in
            
            if (abs(value.translation.height) <= (metrics.size.height/2.0 - metrics.size.width/2)) {
                state = value.translation
            }
            print("state = \(state)")
        }.onChanged { value in
        }.onEnded{ value in
        }
        
    }

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { g in
            ZStack {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25)
                    .fill(.black)

                Circle()
                    .fill(Color.blue)
                    .frame(width: g.size.width, height: g.size.width)
                    .offset(y:translation.height)

                if let fingerLocation = fingerLocation {
                    Circle()
                        .stroke(Color.green, lineWidth: 2)
                        .frame(width: 44, height: 44)
                        .position(fingerLocation)
                }
            }
            .simultaneousGesture(
                fingerDrag.simultaneously(with: simpleDrag(for: g))
            )
        }
    }
    
}

And here is the main view:
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var handler : TouchHandler = TouchHandler()
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Text("\(handler.touches.count)")
                .frame(width:100, height: 100)
                .background(.black.opacity(0.3))
                .position(CGPoint(x: 100.0, y: 100.0))
            
            ForEach(0..<handler.touches.count, id:\.self) { index in
                Text("\(handler.touches[index].x)")
                    .position(handler.touches[index])
                Circle().fill(Color.white)
                    .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                    .shadow(color: .red, radius: 10)
                    .position(handler.touches[index])
                    .rotationEffect(.degrees(360))
            }
            
            VStack {
                Image(systemName: "globe")
                    .imageScale(.large)
                    .foregroundStyle(.tint)
                Text("Hello, world!")
                TestView2()
                    .frame(width:40, height: 200)

                MultitouchView { touches in
                    print(touches)
                    handler.touches = touches
                }
                .frame(height:200)
                .background(.black.opacity(0.1))
            }
            .padding()

        }
        .onChange(of: handler.touches, { print ("Hello Change") } )
        
    }
}

The multi-touch view does not record new touches when the drag gesture slider is activated.

I have filed a feedback report with Apple. As a workaround, I use a UITouch UIkit view wrapped in a SwiftUI UIViewRepresentable, and now I can get touch events from either view. I'll update this thread when I get back a reply from Apple. If anyone has any other suggestions, please let us know here!
